# 'harvest' as a metaphor -- alternatives

Tags: expressions, metaphors

I was wondering if it is fine to write

> From this project, I have learned [blah blah], and this is the most important **harvest** I have received from this project.

What is a better metaphor or better way to express the meaning?

Comment: *Harvest* wouldn't normally be used in this construction. *"This is the most important **benefit** I have received from this project"*, for example, would be common. I would use *"primary"* rather than *"most important"*, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: What about *lesson*?

Comment: the product or result of an action: in terms of science, Apollo yielded a meager harvest. ... http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/harvest

Not a normal use of the word, but it does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The most important benefit I have received from this project is having
>   learnt that

would avoid needless repetition and still convey the intended meaning.

Answer (score 4):

I would say this is the most important thing I have *gleaned* from this project.

*Glean* [has one definition of](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/glean) "To gather (something) slowly and carefully in small pieces." It also has a relationship to harvesting, with its other definition: "To gather (grain) left behind by reapers."

Answer (score 2):

This is *the greatest reward I've reaped* from this project.

Answer (score 1):

How about *finding*?

> This is the most important [or significant] *finding* from this project.

NOAD lists, under ***finding***:

> a conclusion reached as a result of an inquiry, investigation, or trial: *experimental findings.*